# Set value of dropdown menu in dynamic table

Tags: jquery, ajax

I cannot preset an option for my  item when I create a table inside "$.get".
If I create a table outside the "$.get" then everything works. How can I preset the value of  when I create a table inside the "$.get"?

```
 $.get("/api/customers/", function (data) {
            for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
                $("#row_0").before("<tr id='row_" +
                    (i + 1) + "'><td><select class='form-control driver_name' style='text-align:right;' id='customer_" +
                    (i + 1) + "'> <option value='8'></option><option value='9'>Customer1</option><option value='10'>Customer2</option><option value='11'>Customer3</option></select></td></tr>");
            }
        }, "json");
```

This one works (without get, but I need get):

```
for (var i = 0, len = 2; i < len; i++) {
                $("#row_0").before("<tr id='row_" +
                    (i + 1) + "'><td><select class='form-control driver_name' style='text-align:right;' id='customer_" +
                    (i + 1) + "'> <option value='8'></option><option value='9'>Customer1</option><option value='10'>Customer2</option><option value='11'>Customer3</option></select></td></tr>");
            }
```

I use (I tried many but nothing works when I create a table inside get):

```
 $("#customer_1").val("10");

            $("#customer_1").get(0).selectedIndex = 2;
```

Comment: Console log `data.length` and see ti's value.

Comment: It's length is 2. Table has two rows. I can see them both with get and without. The problem is that I cannot set the value of <select> when I create a table inside get.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I had to set the value inside of the get and inside the loop.

```
 $.get("/api/customers/", function (data) {
            for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
                $("#row_0").before("<tr id='row_" +
                    (i + 1) + "'><td><select class='form-control driver_name' style='text-align:right;' id='customer_" +
                    (i + 1) + "'> <option value='8'></option><option value='9'>Customer1</option><option value='10'>Customer2</option><option value='11'>Customer3</option></select></td></tr>");

$("#customer_"+(i+1)).val("10");////HERE
            }
        }, "json");
```